# Word with a meaning of "personal internal struggle"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

A word for a thing that someone can mentally struggle with, or has a quirk for, kind of like (but not) hubris.

I've seen it around, but only a few times, and I can't for the life of me think what it was! I think it had something to do with neuro? Not neurotic, though.

As in 'Alexis struggled with many (word)'.

---

***Neuroses*** was the word I was looking for, thank you @stevesliva !

Comment: There could be many words that can fit in your example sentence. Please show us one situation where you would feel you are struggling with the word. What causes the struggle?

Comment: I leaned that in Arabic, the word *jihad* is much closer to this notion than to "war against the infidels" (though it has both senses, arising from the root sense of "struggle against the forces which tend to corrupt").

Comment: Maybe, “***inner demons***”?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for is *neuroses*, from the singular *neurosis*. A plain English synonym being might be *hangups*.

Comment: What does it mean to 'have a quirk for' something?

Comment: Comment made an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for *neuroses*, from the singular *neurosis*. A plain English synonym being might be *hangups*.

> [***neurosis***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/neurosis) - (in non-technical use) excessive and irrational anxiety or obsession
>
> [***hang-up***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hang-up) - An emotional problem or inhibition

(*Oxford Dictionaries*)

Answer (score 0):

The word you could be thinking of may be, "*dilemma*," which is defined as "a situation in which a difficult choice has to be made between two or more alternatives, especially equally undesirable ones: the people often face the dilemma of feeding themselves or their cattle," by the New Oxford American Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say such a person is ***[conflicted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conflict)***.

> **1.1** (as **adjective conflicted**) Having or showing confused and mutually inconsistent feelings:
>   *‘he remains a little conflicted about Marlene’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conflict

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:
fighting one's demons
also face/struggle with

> When things are particularly rough, it may
>   seem as if the demons are winning. But as long as you’re still living
>   and breathing, you are the victor.
>  [goodtherapy.org, How to face
>   your demons](https://www.goodtherapy.org/blog/face-your-demons-1103114/)

To me suggests a fight or struggle.

[How do you fight/battle your inner demons?, Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080307202310AAEyzt7&guccounter=1)

> We like Batman - we understand him, we suffer with him. On the other
>   hand, we want to be Superman. But they're conflicting philosophies.
>   Let's bring them together in one movie and see how we, as an audience,
>   wrestle with our inner demons.
>   [BrainyQuote.com](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/wolfgang_petersen_184343)